# Difference between 可靠 and 实在？

Tags: vocabulary

A quick question. I appreciate that 实在 can also be an adverb, but as an adjective, how does it differ in its usage from 可靠？ They both come out roughly as reliable, dependable.

What is the difference between a 实在的人 and a 可靠的人?

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

实在的人 = pragmatic person

可靠的人 = reliable/ dependable person

*Your confusion might come from you thinking "One can rely on pragmatic people to do thing well". Thus make pragmatic people also be reliable people*

Answer (score 1):

可means could；靠means reliable. 可靠means something or someone could be reliable to.
If we just look at words，实在means something is full inside. We can redard it as ‘no cheats’. It usually means someone is honest or without bad ideas.